# Python OpenCV Camera Calibration cv::imshow error

Tags: python, opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I am trying to calibrate an SJ4000 camera using OpenCV 2.4.11 in Python 2.7 in Anaconda.

However, I am unable to run the script available here: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html#setup

I am even testing it with the sample images available in `samples/cpp/`, images `left01.jpg to left14.jpg`. It is able to detect the chessboard in the images, but once it hits this line:

```
cv2.imshow('img',img)
```

It throws an error:

```
error: ..\..\..\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

EDIT 1: After further debugging, I have found that `img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners2,ret)` results in a None object.

How do I solve this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: check `img` it can be `None`

Comment: This is as highly descriptive as all OpenCV errors, but it basically means that it fails the assertion `size.width>0 && size.height>0`. i.e. your image is probably 0x0 in size, or doesn't exist.

Comment: @furas - Yes, it turned out to be `None` but why?

Comment: What is `img` before that? In fact, is it not `None` right after `img = cv2.imread(fname)`?

Comment: check `img` before `drawChessboardCorners` maybe problem is somewhere before this line. I found that CV doesn't raise error when there is some problem but it returns `None` - ie. it returns `None` when it can't get image from camera.

Comment: @Iluvatar - No, it reads the image and a matrix is printed out.

Comment: @furas - Before that function it still exists, a matrix is printed out and it's not `None`. I am starting to think - is this an installation issue?

Comment: If it's not `None` before `drawChessboardCorners`, then probably either `corners2` or `ret` has a bad value, so it's returning None as an error.

Comment: @Iluvatar - You're right: `ret` returns `True` but `corners2` returns `None`. Do you have any idea why this might be the case? Because this code is literally what's stated on the site and I'm using the images they used in the example. I don't understand why it wouldn't work, apart from it being due to an installation issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hooray! All solved after some further debugging. I suspect this is a version issue.

I changed

```
corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
imgpoints.append(corners2)
# Draw and display the corners
img1 = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners2,ret)
```

To

```
cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
# Draw and display the corners
cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners,ret)
```

And everything works perfectly!

Comment: Realize now the reason it didn't work is `drawChessboardCorners()` operates on the image directly, and doesn't return anything. Which also means you can still save `corners2` if you want.